# Why was my non-programming question on StackOverflow closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I feel that programmers have special requirements so I don't feel this is an unsuitable question:

> [Good backup software for programmers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217306/good-backup-software-for-programmers/1217332#1217332)

Comment: it was migrated to SU: http://superuser.com/questions/16886

Comment: When something doesn't go your way, throwing a tantrum and calling others the zealots is a great way to get the sympathy vote.

Comment: Good Lord, you're not even really complaining that it's closed, but that people **moved it to the right site for you.**

Comment: Community does not appreciate name calling.

Comment: Community does not appreciate being called Community. It prefers Francesca

Comment: Francesca wishes you guys would quit blaming her for everything.  She does the best job she can!

Comment: I am so tempted right now to modify the community user on SuperUser.

Comment: @TheTXI: Rename it to Rich B and give it my avatar. Watch the hilarity ensue!

Comment: @Rich B: That *would* be funny. TheTXI, do you suppose you could flagrantly misuse your mod powers and risk a permanent ban?

Comment: @mmyers: Sounds like a good suggestion for meta!

Comment: Is SuperUser open for the general public yet?  I haven't noticed an announcement.  I'd be annoyed if I asked a question and it was moved to where I couldn't see the answers, whether or not it was the right thing.

Comment: Anyone can use SuperUser, just get the password from the SO blog. It should be trivial to find with a simple search.

Comment: @David: Because Ian's being uber-cryptic: ewok.adventure ...enjoy!

Comment: Rename *her* to Francesca on Halloween, or April 1st.

Answer (score 14):

Adding "for programmers" to it doesn't make it programming related. There are plenty of good backup questions already asked on SuperUser. Despite what you may believe, programmers and normal people aren't all that different when it comes to backing up files on a system.

If you wanted to talk about source control systems, that is more StackOverflow, but basic backup related questions have been and will continue to be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: Remember that we mere mortals can't see SuperUser; it just says it's in "private beta". I'm guessing from the answers here that many SO power users have SU access, but that just means that those most likely to post an OT question to SO are those least likely to be able to post it to the proper site, or even to see their question if it gets moved to SU.

Comment: Jay, you are mot than capable of getting in there with the password which is available on the SO blog.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that... right after I posted.  That should lose me points somewhere!  OTOH, I -thought- I already subscribed to the OS blog, but I don't - just Coding Horror.  OTOOH, seems like if your question's moved there, that'd be a really good spot in the UI to point people at that blog post..

Answer (score 7):

It is not a programming question. Therefore it does not belong on SO.com.

Try and read the FAQ before posting, and especially before going on a foolish tirade.

Not only was the question not appropriate for the site you posted it on, it was a horrible question in general in need of serious editing. And you are complaining that your question was closed, when it was, in fact, moved to a site where it is much more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

That is because you pretty much asked for "What backup programs are available?" , which is a superuser type question. There is no specific programmer backup software.  Backup is backing up your files and every feature you requested in part of most standard backup solutions.  That comment about ask question and insert "for programmers" was spot on for this question and many moved/closed/dup questions.

It was moved for good reason.

Do not take things personal when questions get moved.  They are helping organize questions and helps you get the answers you want quicker because they are in the correct place.

Answer (score 2):

Because the community says so.

It wasn't actually about programming. Backup is backup is backup. It's been asked several times in SF and SU (unless you are looking for CVS info).

Answer (score 1):

If the question was more in line of "Do software developers have different backup requirements than end users?" and it had some examples of why you think so, I think it could have merit.  Here are some possible examples of interesting items a backup software might need to handle:

- Backing up files from inside a Virtual PC.  Can the backup software mount the .vhd file as a volume and back up individual files instead of one large file.
- Not backing up source code that is under version control, because the the computer is not the authoritative source.
- Not backing up files easily download from the source distribution (e.g. vendor software, OSS project, etc).

Some of these answers might just be best practices in data organization with use of specific settings of the backup software.