# Can we please stop closing perfectly good questions that the community enjoys?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, popularity

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265525/contest-fastest-way-to-sort-a-big-array-of-gaussian-distributed-data) yesterday. It has 23 upvotes and 9 stars, which shows the community is enjoying it. It is about programming, about a very real problem (even though it is simplified for the sake of the question), and can be answered objectively (with code). Even more, it's the kind of question I would love being able to Google in one or two years when I will run into the problem again.

Can people please stop trying to close it or migrate it to an obscure Stack Exchange site that has almost no visitors?

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is immature and doesn't help.

Comment: It wasn't me, but this is Meta... new game, new rules, unfortunately...

Comment: It wasn't a **perfectly good question**, at least not a mainstream question. It described itself as a *contest*.

Comment: Down-votes in meta is just a sign of disagreement.

Comment: @user139018: I disagree with your post, therefore I downvoted. I also disagree with your comment _about_ downvoting. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87475/add-a-note-about-downvoting-on-meta

Comment: By the way, I think it's a great question _for the CG site_. I upvoted it over there now that Jeff has migrated it.

Comment: And it's worth noting that 23 upvotes and 9 favorites indicates 31 users total who explicitly indicated some measure of approval... out of some 400 *thousand* users, that's not really saying much.

Comment: @Soft: 23 + 9 = 31 + 1 :)

Comment: @Josh: Crap! Apparently my brain's already gone to bed but didn't inform the rest of me!  But the point still holds.  I am at a complete loss as to how I can touch-type, reading what I type as I type it, and even so, typos still slip by.

Comment: All this flak simply goes to show that SO isn't a community-driven site, but a high-rep-addict-driven site. People with enough rep to do moderation don't give a damn what the community wants.

Comment: As a side note I (one of the *pro tem* mods on CodeGolf.SE) would suggest that *"Don't put [question on topic for [site]] on [site] because [site] has no traffic"* is a self fulfilling prophesy. Questions on CodeGold.SE [*have* gotten a lot a traffic](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), and what we need there are more really engaging tasks. This one looks promising to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are questions closed immediately?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92636/why-are-questions-closed-immediately), [Why was my non-programming question on StackOverflow closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12122/why-was-my-non-programming-question-on-stackoverflow-closed)

Comment: @Software Monkey: it's more than the vast majority of questions on this site.

Comment: @user139018 «SO isn't a community-driven site, but a high-rep-addict-driven site» Users with close votes are part of the community, too, not some shadowy cabal in a smoke-filled back room. The names of those who vote to close, open, edit, etc. are in the public record. Do you propose that every single member of the site be consulted whenever a question is closed?

Comment: @Cody Gray: please explain why my question is "Not programming". I'm really looking forward to your explanation.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: no, I wouldn't suggest that. But for example, you could require at least the number of upvotes + 5 close votes to close a question. In this case, the few zealots that closed the question clearly went against the will of the community (at large, not the zealots that read meta).

Comment: Downvooooooohohote partaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay!

Comment: @random: it's more fun than actually making the site better, isn't it? :)

Comment: Which is why we close off topic questions in the first place.

Comment: @random: by which you mean programming questions on a programming questions website. Of course. Good night, I give up.

Comment: @User139018: My point was only that 32 users showing approval out of 1/2 a million total is not indicative one way or the other of a good and appropriate question.

Comment: The fact that people *like* a question does not mean that it is on-topic or that it belongs. I can think of about 94 joke questions that I could post that would probably get as many upvotes. But something would be *seriously* broken if they didn't get closed by the community. **Obviously most people don't think the question belonged.** You're blaming the close vote on the 5 users who voted to close, but since you brought it up on Meta, you haven't had anyone else vote to re-open it. No one seems to agree that it's been closed in error. That's far more than 5 users.

Comment: This is why democracy as a principle is flawed.

Answer (score 13):

I went ahead and migrated this to Code Golf.

Per their faq:

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq

I believe it is on topic there -- we have an objective set of criteria for measuring a winner.

Comment: Thanks for at least reopening it. I still disagree that it's not on topic for stack overflow though: it's objective, about a real problem, and about programming. I agree the title was maybe poorly worded, though.

Comment: The majority disagrees with you though. You should ask it again as a concrete question instead of a puzzle which just isn't appropriate on [so].

Comment: @Octavian Damiean: the majority of meta, but clearly not the majority of SO. This is the core of the problem: high-rep users are clearly abusing their powers and bugging normal people like me all the time instead of improving the site.

Comment: So the entire world is wrong and you are still right?

Comment: @Octavian Damiean : the entire world of people mad enough to participate in meta, which would be the 19 people that downvoted the question... Anyways, I'm not the only one that thinks that way, competition will appear one day or the other, and someone will start a more open site. Good riddance!

Answer (score 12):

For such kind of questions there is [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

It is just not appropriate on Stack Overflow. It was in the past maybe but not anymore.

Comment: As I said: this is not a "programming puzzle", I don't care much about micro-optimizations (which the code golf guys are probably going to do). It's a real programming question, that boils down to: does knowing the statistical distribution of data make sorting faster? Since the answers to my last questions were inconclusive, I figured a contest would settle it

Answer (score 7):

I think such a situation arose only because of the style of the question.
You didn't ask the community to help you with some problem.
You said: what do you think about such a problem? Who can beat it up?
This is exactly what the `Code Golf` site is created for, but not `StackOverflow`.
And such questions there can move CG up in the Google search.

Comment: +1 especially for "such questions can move CG up in the Google"

Comment: As I said: this is not a "programming puzzle", I don't care much about micro-optimizations (which the code golf guys are probably going to do). It's a real programming question, that boils down to: does knowing the statistical distribution of data make sorting faster? Since the answers to my last questions were inconclusive, I figured a contest would settle it.

Comment: *"I don't care much about micro-optimizations (which the code golf guys are probably going to do)"* We tackle all types of objective programming puzzle on CodeGolf.SE, and this comment makes me suspect that you haven't really *looked* at the site. This is a *good* task, and it's relevance to the real world is likely to make it *more* not less interesting to CodeGolf.SE users.

Comment: Sorry but your stack exchange site is very poorly named. Code golfing is a futile quest (even though it's fun!). It doesn't sound like serious questions like this one are welcome.

Comment: If you don't like the site-naming, you can start another one on Area-51. Name it Seriously-Questions-About-Coding :) Why you just can't accept the situation? Community didn't understood you this time - get better prepared for next time.

Comment: Have actually ever read the title of the site? It is [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Note the _Programming Puzzles_ in the name?

Comment: @user: The domain name is related to the historical place of code-golf as the one and only sanctioned type of contest on Stack Overflow, and it is a little bit of a problem. So we have a slightly awkward phrasing for the site title in an attempt to counter that. Those are the breaks.