# Where is my snowflake on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

My friend just showed his Stack Overflow account. A `snowflake` button is visible near to achievements button (top header, black background). It's not visible in my account. I am not seeing this snowflake icon in my account. Should I do something to see this button in my account?

Comment: Which site, OS, browser? Have you tried other sites and browsers?

Comment: @Kevin stackoverflow.com, desktop chrome 38

Comment: I believe SO was automatically opted out. Do you see it here or, say, [scifi.se]?

Comment: @Kevin I got the snowflake automatically. But I had to click on it and say "join" before I got to see the hats. Everywhere else on the network auto-joined.

Comment: Please see the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/1438): "I'm on Stack Overflow (or on one of a few other sites). Where are my hats?" But if you don't have a snowflake at all, there might be something else going on.

Comment: I think it was a cache problem. Multiple times I've pressed CTRL+F5, then snowflake appeared. Or maybe it appeared because of I asked a question. But I remember I've pressed CTRL+F5 before I ask question. Interesting! So, problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using Chrome Data Compression Proxy plugin, and browser couldn't load http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/core.js?2 file completely and gave `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL core.js?2:1` error (Because browser couldn't parse loaded js file, core.js file is ended with `addSpinner(),$.ajax({"url":"` text which is not valid javascript file). Everything is fine in browser console except that error. If I disable this plugin, everything works fine and show snowflake.