# Do all sites have Winterbash?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

The [Winter Bash FAQ](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/faq) mentions:

> #### I'm on Stack Overflow (or on one of a few other sites). Where are my hats?
>
> Users on these sites have to choose to opt-in individually. Just click the "Winter Bash" popup at the top and click "I love hats!", and you'll be able to earn hats and see other hat-loving users sporting dashing works of millinery.

I don't see a pop-up (snowflake) on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com), nor is it listed in the [Winter Bash Leaderboard](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard). Are all sites able to participate in Winter Bash 2014? What about per-site metas (as it's currently not available on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com))?

<sub>Related (not duplicate): [Where is my snowflake on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245179/168244); I tried in both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox with no luck, nor am I running any of mentioned extensions/plug-ins.</sub>

Comment: I have removed the "few other sites" from the FAQ; this year Stack Overflow is the only such site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This year the breakdown is as follows:

- Stack Overflow by default has no hats, but users can opt in to wear and see them (either by clicking "I love hats" in the snowflake dropdown, or simply by putting on a hat somewhere).
- TeX, Math Overflow, and Japanese Stack Overflow have no hats at all, with no way of opting in.
- The [experimental edX sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231238/115866) have no hats either, period.
- All other Q&A sites (except for discuss.area51) have hats, and they're enabled by default.

Comment: This is intriguing. It makes me curious: why does TeX not participate?

Comment: Because they didn't want to.

Comment: Fair enough! It sounded like there was some other restriction, but perhaps I read it wrong.

Comment: @Emrakul: This was confirmed by the mods. It was [brought up in 2012](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3113/5764) with very little feedback and was dropped. The same for 2013, and now as well for 2014.

Comment: @balpha: Around when is the opt-in time for sites? Perhaps I can post a question on Meta.TeX.SE around that time next year and see if things have changed.

Comment: @Werner I'm not sure, but I'll ping someone who knows.

Comment: @Werner: This past year it was from mid-November to Dec. 1. I imagine next year will be around the same time.

Comment: Maybe worth adding Area 51 also doesn't have hats?

Comment: @Werner it is that time.

Comment: @JonEricson: Is this the time to question a site for participation?

Comment: @Werner: The moderators have been notified and are considering participation as we speak. Our expectation is that at most a couple of sites will decline. It might be as few as one.

Comment: Thanks @JonEricson... For what it's worth, I've [solicited some community discussion on TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6406/5764)...

Answer (score 4):

To the second, easy answer: hats are not enabled on per-site metas.

Additionally, sites have the option of opting out of Winterbash for 2014. Given that TeX neither appears on the leaderboards nor has the Winterbash plugin, I'd assume that for one reason or another they decided to opt out.

Comment: Who are "they"? Any reference for the "per-site meta" answer?

Comment: @Werner "They" being the TeX community.

Comment: There was no mention of this in the the [TeX.SE chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) nor on [Meta.TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com) (as far as I know), so I doubt "[we] decided to opt out."

Comment: @Werner TeX decided to opt out last year, so it may have unintentionally carried over in the absence of discussion. I'll ping one of their mods.

Comment: [I already pinged the mods in that regard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19069535#19069535)...

Comment: There were definitely hats last year, though. I mean: on TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Child metas now have hats (if parent site has hats)!
From [balpha's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280387/2982225):

> You wear the same hat on the child meta that you wear on the parent site, and the hat count on a meta user profile takes you to your hat rack on the parent site, similar to how it works for profile editing.