# How did the Community user earn the Bugdroid hat?

Tags: support, community-user, winter-bash-2014

I understand from [this related answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/223099) that the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) can earn hats.  The explanation there is rather straightforward. However, [viewing the hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community#winter-bash) in the Community user's profile shows that it has earned the [Bugdroid](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/bugdroid) hat which requires the "user" to:

> post, vote, edit, or comment with the Android app

How does a *pseudo user* representing background processes that scrub the site interact with the SE app for Android, and specifically for *drupal.se*?

Comment: They don't like to share the secret, but the Stack Exchange servers run on Android devices.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several reasons why this can happen, but in this case a question on drupal.se was flagged as spam from the Android app, and if the spam flag comes from the Android app, then so does the community user's automatic downvote that comes for free with a spam flag.