# Naruto & Selfie Hats

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

I have some doubts about how earn these hats.

> **Selfie**
>
> > ask and answer your own question

I did a [Selfie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497987/android-elevation-is-not-showing-a-shadow-under-a-customview) yesterday, but nothing happened <strike>(yet).</strike>
I earned this hat right now. <strike>I guess that this post woke up some process.</strike> As @ShadowWizard said *You got Selfie due to the upvote on the question. :)*

> **Naruto**
>
> > post an accepted answer that receives no other votes for 12 hours

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477457/passing-scope-variables-defined-in-http-request-from-controller-to-directive/27477793#27477793) with no upvotes (accepted 20 hours ago), but I have not earned the hat (yet)

Is it just lag? Or are there other rules not written in the description of these hats?

Comment: Chances are good that some hats are awarded in a process that executes only once a day at 0 GMT.  Your question and answer occurred today.  I don't know when your answer was accepted on the second hat attempt, but if it occurred after 0 GMT then it's also likely that this is awarded only once per day.  Wait another 8 or so hours and see if you get them at 0 GMT.

Comment: Most likely both question and answer have to get at least one upvote first. Dunno for Naruto though.

Comment: @AdamDavis was accepted 20 hours ago

Comment: From observations, Selfie is awarded for both asking a question and answering it within the Winterbash period, with both the question and answer having a score greater than zero.

Comment: Maybe you must not edit the answer if you want the Naruto hat? Really not sure. The [only user I found with this hat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo) got two accepted answers without votes, both not edited.

Comment: You got Selfie due to the upvote on the question. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: scratch that, it was edited in the grace period.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how do you know? And even if true, maybe one of the "secret" requirements is no revisions. (and you also have such an answer on SO :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard: because I remember editing the answer. Looking at the revision history I also see it was deleted, then undeleted...

Comment: You mean your answer @Martijn?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27482093). It was briefly deleted as I verified that the OP had indeed botched their indentation, and further edited after undeletion,  but within the grace period.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: interestingly enough, the question did receive an upvote (and a downvote, and was closed).

Comment: @MartijnPieters so more likely the secret demand is have the question closed as well?

Comment: It could be possible that the answer was upvoted and the upvote was retracted, and that throws off the script.

Comment: @animuson nop upvote and unupvote occurred

Comment: @ShadowWizard: more likely the secret demand is that the question has votes, perhaps limited to *at least one upvote*.

Comment: @OneWay There's no possible way for you to know that as upvotes and unupvotes that occur on the same day get collapsed and you don't see them. That's why I suggested it as a possibility.

Comment: @animuson That would indeed prevent the hat (and that is intentional), but in this case it's probably a bug in the awarding logic. I'll look soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Selfie has already been [explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245389/naruto-selfie-hats/245395#245395); also see [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer).

The Naruto issue was indeed a bug; an overzealous optimization that caused the awarding to fail when the time between the answer being written and being accepted was too long. I've fixed that bug, and you have just been awarded the Naruto. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

Selfie (and "On the Road") requires the posted question to have a score of 1 or higher.

I just got "Selfie" from a question I posted hours ago, just a moment after someone upvoted it.

Comment: @Cerberus You deserve Eureka

Comment: Hehe, thanks, but I don't think eureka applies to figuring out mechanics behind normal hats :P

Comment: Why not? if these hats have "secret" requirements..

Comment: I wouldn't mind :P

Comment: @OneWay They're not really secret. They published a FAQ explaining that there would be hidden requirements to prevent abuse for many of them before the Winterbash started. Unlike the secret hats which have no details whatsoever.

Comment: @animuson oh, well. thanks! i will read FAQ as soon.