# Why did I not get the Explorer hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

The Explorer hat's trigger is

> post an accepted answer that receives no other votes for 12 hours

(which is the same as the Naruto hat from 2014.)

This is [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/97112/2217) (the post [timeline](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/97112/timeline)), where I think I fulfilled all of the hats requirements.

- It was longer then 12 hours since the answer was accepted.
- The answer has no votes.
- The answer is not a self answer.
- The answer (and question) were posted during the winter bash.

I have read the other "y no hat" questions and the problems are things that I have mentioned in here as already fulfilled.

[Why wasn't the explorer hat awarded for an answer that appears to fulfill the requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304637/278094)

I'm kind of hoping that there is some bug, like there was [last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245389/278094).

Comment: And the question is upvoted (and has been for ~18 hours, so not a recent vote + hat-award delay).

Comment: Winter Bash – that time of the year when people complain about getting upvotes ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone *did* vote on your post a couple of hours after it was accepted. The vote was just retracted about 20 seconds after it was cast.

Comment: Probably because the upvoter later noticed the OP's [comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97066/duplicate-of-an-object-vanishes-when-starting-the-blender-game/97112#comment171674_97112) asking people not to upvote it, and therefore retracted the vote. Since that's not really in the spirit of the hat, I think it's completely fine that the hat wasn't awarded :)

Comment: @balpha and animuson thanks. I'm not stupid with the bash stuff. I knew it had to either be a bug (unlikely), or somebody voted and retracted it. :/ Well here goes again...