# Can you get Naruto for Posting a Selfie?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

You can get the Naruto hat for posting an answer, getting accepted, and receiving no votes for 12 hours. My question is: Can you accept your own answer and still be awarded Naruto? Or is Naruto only awarded for answering some one else's question?

Okay.... I'll admit it. This is certainly gaming. What can I say? *I like hats*, but I would not blatantly *cheat* either. Any Q & A I post would **absolutely** be a good and legitimate Q & A and if someone happens to post a better answer than mine, I would certainly give them the checkmark... eventually.

Comment: Asking on meta instead of actually trying it in the first place definitely deserves a +1.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Waiting for *no* upvotes?  Ain't nobody got time for that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't.

From [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer)

> ## Sometimes your own things don't count
>
> In some cases, there may be an unmentioned requirement for certain things to be outside your control, lest it be too easy to get a hat. In particular this is often the case for hats involving accepted answers where self-answers are excluded.

Comment: I missed that Q&A. Thank you very much.

Comment: I disagree that the example in my [suggested edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/34291) wasn't needed @animuson. I didn't suggest it for my health. That example is exactly what made it click in my head.

Answer (score 4):

While I cannot *confirm* anything, I can tell you that the answer is **almost certainly not**. Stack Exchange has a history of not counting self-answers for awards (e.g. guru or enlightened badges, or the pizza hat).