# Bill Lumbergh - all 5 questions in a single Saturday?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

From description of [Bill Lumbergh](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/bill-lumbergh) hat -

> answer 5 questions on a Saturday (in UTC time)

Two questions:

- Do all 5 answers have to be on the same Saturday ? (or can they spread across various (read 3) Saturdays)
- Do we need at least 1 upvote per answer for all 5 answers ?

  - If yes, then do we need the upvote on the same day, or upvotes can come later on anytime (before 5th Jan, of course)

Comment: *various Saturdays*, there are only 3 in the Winter Bash..

Comment: Yes, an upvote is needed for all 5, no, the votes don't have to take place on the Saturday.

Comment: How are you so sure ? (about the not have to take place on saturday) ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, see the FAQ I linked from my answer.

Comment: I already have the hat, it was awarded right after a 5th answer got an upvote.

Comment: That link still does not say a word about this particular case about what is the time limit of getting upvotes

Comment: @Optimizer: yes, it does: *If the hat has an additional date requirement, it is okay if the upvote comes in after the time is already over, as long as the content was created during the time.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah. I blame myself for not actually opening the link :P

Comment: Please note that I have edited the answer to your question; the version you accepted was incorrect.

Comment: @balpha oh! The wording/grammar of the hat description surely is incorrect then!

Comment: The way I read it I don't feel it's wrong, but I agree it's definitely unclear. I'll change the wording.

Comment: @balpha the `a` hints on the fact that its a single Saturday

Comment: The fact that you even asked this question shows that it's not unambiguous, though :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, the answers do not all have to be posted on the same saturday.

There is an [implicit quality requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer/245123#245123) for all hats tied to posting:

> To prevent people from posting nonsense just to earn a hat, most hats that require creating content, especially questions and answers, have some requirements that may not be mentioned in the hat description. Generally this involves questions/answers having a positive score (i.e. getting at least one upvote), not being closed/deleted, etc.

Your 5 answers must all score 1 or more.

Don't worry, if those votes come tomorrow or later, but still within the Winter Bash period, you'll still be awarded the hat then.

Comment: @Sompuperoo that review hat had no where explicitly mentioned a time limit. this one has

Comment: @Sompuperoo since no explicit mention about that, so I guess *any* question is fine.

Comment: @balpha: ninja edit! :-P