# Why is the Community User collecting hats, and who decides what she wears?

Tags: discussion, community-user, winter-bash-2014

I do understand the role of the community user - it is a record keeping device that owns all activity that is no longer controlled by a specific named user. Even with that knowledge, however, I found this interesting:

[image]

1. Are unowned hats going to Community as well?
2. How does Community figure out what hat she's (he?) going to wear? Is it random, or, is the Crab intentional?
3. Was this intentional or just an interesting feature? Put another way, are the devs who implemented hats that on top of things that they considered this? If so, well, my hats off to you!

Answer (score 6):

Apologies for answering part of my own question, after having found the answer.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/216898 says that community user:
a. is a she
b. is in fact just another user
c. is not filtered out, because it is fun
d. is appropriately dressed by a moderator.

Apologies for doing further research after finding the answer, but if nothing else, this will serve as good signpost for others who are wondering the same thing.

Comment: Fun fact: She is wearing a different hat on every site.