# Why does the Community user wear the 'Ooh, Shiny!' hat on Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, meta, community-user, winter-bash-2017

I just noticed on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150168/295232) that the [Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user wears the 'Ooh, Shiny!' secret hat on Meta Stack Exchange. This is not the case on other sites, like [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) and a handful of others I checked.

[image]

It probably earned this hat

> due to the [Roomba](/help/roomba) script, or when an OP confirmed a duplicate

but why does it *wear* a hat, and only here?

Comment: It has worn hats in the past too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246055/why-is-the-community-user-collecting-hats-and-who-decides-what-she-wears ;-)

Comment: I wonder how the Community user got the Too Cool hat. As far as I know, the Community user votes automatically and not from the app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderators can change the hat settings for the community user, so I'd guess a moderator here did that.

You can see another example [with the community user on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) where I just added the hat.

Comment: Just curious, how do you do that? Do you login to the Community user?

Comment: @Panda no, it works exactly as it would for my own profile. I simply go to the community user profile and change the hat.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that. Of course, the option 'wear this hat on all sites' has been disabled :(

Comment: The IPS Community user is also wearing a hat. :D @Glorfindel