# What does manually award a bounty mean?

Tags: support, badges, bounties

What does "manually award a bounty" mean? I was looking under the badges and I found it under "Benefactor". And I have awarded a bounty on my question before, so why don't I have it? And if needed, could the description be improved?

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/258839/revisions)'s the question with the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you *manually* click the blue button next to the answer to award the answerer *yourself*, rather than the Community user awarding it herself.

In your question, you can see the bounty wasn't *awarded*, it was merely *started*.

*You* need to *manually* award the bounty by clicking the blue '+50' (or whatever the bounty value is) button next to the answer you like.

> [image]

Comment: herself? Community is a bot, they don't have genders

Comment: @UnicornsAreVeryVeryYummy see the bottom of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/260841) ;)