# How would one get the Darth Vader hat if they can't post or upvote because they don't have enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I heard you can get a cool darth vader hat by posting/commenting here, but you need reputation to post and comment, so that won't work. Are there any other ways do get it ;D

Comment: A lot of the hats have varying reputation levels as inherent requirements. If you want them, you'll have to get some reputation.

Comment: Damn, I thought asking the above question would get me the hat but it didn't work...

Comment: Hats are not awarded instantaneously.

Comment: Does  that mean there is a meta on each individual site? i.e stackoverflow?

Comment: @rene I earned a Darth Vader hat on this site this morning, so they *are* handed out on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: "but you need reputation to post and comment, so that won't work" but you just posted here... I don't get what you're saying (other than posting this just to get the hat...)

Comment: See the last point in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer about meta hats.

Comment: Agree with @Cai this appears to be just trolling to get the hat.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP asked just to get the hat, wasting other people's time in the process.

Comment: Sorry I guess I misjudged this, didn't intend to troll.

Answer (score 1):

> but you need reputation to post and comment

Wrong.

You can post both questions and answers here on Meta Stack Exchange with 1 rep (you did post this very question!) and you can post comments on your own questions and answers to your questions.

When you get the hat here, you can wear it on all sites.

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the 'I am your father' hat on Meta Stack Exchange in a few minutes; you don't need any reputation to post here. Apparently, for this hat's purpose, Meta Stack Exchange counts as its own Meta.

For other sites (except Math Overflow), you'll need 5 reputation before posting on Meta, unless you post a question about your own post on the main site. That would be another way to obtain the hat. Make sure it's a good (Meta) question, though.