# No hat for silver badge on meta

Tags: support, badges, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

Some hours ago I was awarded the Good Question badge on Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question?userid=1529630

It's a silver badge, but I didn't receive the [925 hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/925)

> earn a silver badge

[image]

Seems a bug, or is it because meta badges are ignored for hats?

Comment: Beat me to it :P I got a Necromancer badge on MSO

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You *don't* earn hats on Meta sites (this site is an exception), unless the description of the hat mentions this explicitly, as in the case of the I Am Your Father hat:

> ask, answer, or vote on the meta site

Even then, you will earn the hat on the main site.

Comment: Do you have any reference about not earning hats on meta sites?

Comment: @Oriol took a while; see the last paragraph of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/295232).

Comment: @Oriol btw, this is the only site where you can theoretically earn all the hats.

Comment: @Braiam how does one earn the 'What's up, Doc?' or 'The Never-Ending Story' here?

Comment: @Glorfindel let me correct: this is the only site where you can theoretically earn mosts of the hats without participating anywhere else.