# What's wrong with the "Hero Of Time" Hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I asked a question at UTC 2:00:16 (16 seconds past UTC 2 am), which was 7 PM in US Mountain Standard Time, but I didn't get the hat for that.

Do I need to be accurate to +/- 10 seconds or something?  Or is the hat broken?

Comment: Maybe it takes time to get added?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question must have at least one upvote in order for the hat to be awarded.

This is confirmed now that you got an upvote and got the hat.

Comment: Even this year, the trigger nowhere mentions about the upvote. Should it be corrected?

Comment: @cincout the upvote requirement has been an implicit requirement for many hats over the years (all the hats that require posting a question or answer and don't have a specific vote count requirement). Therefore they didn't think they should mention it in every hat description where it's relevant.