# Why wasn't the explorer hat awarded for an answer that appears to fulfill the requirements?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

[The explorer hat states that the requirements to earn such the hat are to:](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/explorer)

> Post an accepted answer that receives no other votes for 12 hours

[The following answer was accepted on December 14th, yet I was not awarded the hat.](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8516/motherboard-for-intel-i5-4440-lga-1150/8519#8519)

[image]

The only up votes on the page are one up vote on the question and one up vote on a comment on the answer. **Neither of these are on the answer.**

Are there further requirements beyond what is written on the page to obtain the hat?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All hats have the implicit requirement of "happened during Winter Bash".  You posted that answer on December 11, before the start.  You can only earn this hat for an answer that you post during Winter Bash.

Comment: I realized there was an error in my question: [the answer was accepted on the 14th, but posted on the 11th.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36ZOC.png) I've edited the post to reflect this. Is the badge still ineligible regardless?

Comment: @JMY1000 that's been the pattern in the past, *and* the description says "post an answer that...".  It doesn't say "have an answer accepted that...".