# Pre-conditions for the SO Goes Flapper

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

The description for the ["SO Goes Flapper"](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/so-goes-flapper) hat says:

> post an answer with fewer than 600 characters that gets accepted while there is a competing answer with more than 600 characters

But, it feels like there are some unspecified pre-conditions for this hat to trigger:

- is there a restriction that the existing answer with more than 600 characters has to be from a different user?
- could the author of the question be the same user as well?
- does the question or/and the competing answer have to be posted during WB?

Comment: There's definitely some other restriction on it not related to multiple posts by the same user, else I would have gotten it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345560/70505).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara could it be the timing - there needs to exist a long answer at the moment one posts a short one?

Comment: I don't think so. My answer was the last one posted.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara right, I've also had no luck here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53807035/771848 even though fits the description of the hat. Updated the question to be a bit more generic.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You do deserve the hat. See the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> is there a restriction that the existing answer with more than 600 characters has to be from a different user?

Yes, this falls under "Sometimes your own things don't count" in [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer)

> could the author of the question be the same user as well?

No, same rule.

> does the question or/and the competing answer have to be posted during WB?

No, just the accepted answer.

---

That said, there was one bug with the implementation. Per the [implicit requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer), both answers need a score of at least 1, but the hat was only awarded if both answers had a score of at least 2.

This is fixed now.

Comment: Yay, I got the hat now!