# No Silencium hat for 15 days

Tags: support, bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

I have got a [question on Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919239/213987) created Dec 12, 2018, 19:58 MSK — and it still has no answers for 15 days.

[image]

Is it a bug?

Comment: Just checking: no deleted answers either, right?

Comment: crosslink to russian meta: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8434/213987

Comment: @Glorfindel Sure, no deleted answers. (I've 10k+ repo on ru-so and can see deleted answers).

Comment: Please, comment your silent downvotes. Is it something wrong in my question? Where should i ask similar things? Metasite is not for such topics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question has a score of 0, and it looks like the question fails to meet the

> #### Implicit quality requirements
>
> To prevent people from posting nonsense just to earn a hat, most hats that require creating content, especially questions and answers, have some requirements that may not be mentioned in the hat description. Generally this involves questions/answers having a positive score (i.e. getting at least one upvote)

(mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/295232))