# Does accepting your own answer count for earning the "Rep Hunter" hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

If I asked 5 questions and answered them all, and then accepted them, would I have earned the [Rep Hunter](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/rep-hunter) hat?

Comment: It is a bit early to ask about hats for winterbash 2019 ...

Comment: @rene you have secret information that it will be used in WB 2019 again? o_O

Comment: I can't see why this was flagged as off-topic. Yes, the Winter Bash is over, but can't we ask about triggers which haven't been revealed yet?

Comment: @hat What do you mean _"not revealed yet"_? This was no secret hat.

Comment: @SouravGhosh yeah, you're right. I dunno where my brain went. (I haven't found it yet, maybe it will come to light sometime. That's no loss, though, I hardly ever use it :} )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this would not have worked.

Source: I've tested it a couple of days ago.

See also: [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245122/295232)

> #### Sometimes your own things don't count
>
> In some cases, there may be an unmentioned requirement for certain things to be outside your control, lest it be too easy to get a hat. In particular this is often the case for hats involving accepted answers where self-answers are excluded.