# Winter Bash hat not being awarded for Gold Badge on main sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

I gained a golden badge more than 12 minutes ago:

[image: the golden badge Steward]

but until now I didn't get the **Foot of the Rainbow** hat, do the hats take so many minutes to be shown in my profile?

---

Please read this comment by [Yaakov Ellis♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339950/winter-bash-hat-not-being-awarded-for-gold-badge-on-main-sites#comment1135798_339950), before you judge this post :

> Looking into this more, and seems that the hat description says that
>   you get it for main or meta, while the actual logic is only awarding
>   it for meta (MSE is treated like a main site). Going to fix that, will
>   require a build, please be patient. You will get it eventually.

Comment: does this question very bad to get all this dv?

Comment: There was *clearly* a lack of patience and any attempt at research on this question. And... members' patience has also been stretched very thinly of late.

Comment: Looking into this more, and seems that the hat description says that you get it for main or meta, while the actual logic is only awarding it for meta (MSE is treated like a main site). Going to fix that, will require a build, please be patient. You will get it eventually.

Comment: Thank you @YaakovEllis so the question was not that bad, it was really a bug :)

Comment: To the DVers why are you DVing this? this is a actual bug report and I can link to [two](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52841748#52841748) other [examples](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52841208#52841208) where the hat has not yet been awarded.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The hat-bot runs evrey 5 minutes. OP waited 12. He should have gotten it.

Comment: @X-27wantstoReinstateMonica 12 minutes seems a very short  space of time. If   several hours had passed then the post would have been received more warmly. But this is Meta, downvotes are a common feature.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Especially on any WB related post this year :/

Comment: Yes @X-27wants I agree, WB, among the MSE flock, is not greeted with smiles and bleatings of approval.

Comment: At this point I've been waiting 14 hours to get "Foot of the Rainbow" for a [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward?userid=3744182) badge that was awarded on 2019-12-09 01:50:13Z.  So at this point it's surely a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update: this fix is up, and [Foot of the Rainbow](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/foot-of-the-rainbow) should now be awarded to all gold badge winners on both main and meta sites. Thanks for your patience.

---

The [FAQ](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/faq) refers to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245122/51).

Some of the hats take more time to receive than others. Yours should hopefully show up soon.

Other reasons for hats not being awarded immediately:

- The hat scheduler itself (the process that awards the hats) runs every five minutes.
- There are potentially other levels of caching involved as well
- Some hats rely on a certain amount of time passing after a specific action happens before the user will qualify

Comment: I found that post too, but it doesn't mention anything about the waiting period between qualifying for the hat and actually getting it. Would you mind adding it (I could do it but obviously I lack access to the implementation specifics.)

Comment: I added more details to my answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll copy it to the semi-FAQ then.

Comment: It's important to note that for "Foot of the Rainbow" it says ***"either"*** meta or main - so if you get multiple gold badges on both the main site and its child meta [you only get a single hat](https://askubuntu.com/users/914627/rob#winter-bash) for the two sites (and two gold badges). --- So instead of answering: "`... winners on both main and meta ...`" that should say: "... winners on ***either*** main or meta ...".

Answer (score 3):

[Like badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298953/295232), hats are awarded by scheduled tasks which run at regular intervals (every *x* minutes).

I'd recommend waiting for 24 hours before assuming there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: I got my first hat in just few seconds, but this one until now, I don't got it, ok I will wait and see what will happen, thank you

Comment: @YCF_L there are several triggers for awarding hats. Some are instant, some take few minutes, and some can take hours.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard thank you, I don't know this, now I do, thank you for your info :)

Comment: I got "Amazing Grace" within 10 minutes of receiving a silver badge, but I still haven't received "Foot of the Rainbow" after 14 hours.  So I don't think this is simply a delay due to task scheduling.