# Is Meta Stack Exchange a Meta site or a Main site for the purposes of the Social Distancing hats?

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, winter-bash-2020

There are two Social distancing hats; one for Main sites and one for Meta sites. I see that I earned both of them on Meta Stack Exchange:

[image: Screenshot of hats earned]

Is Meta Stack Exchange actually both a Meta site and a Main site, or is this a bug in how the conditions for the hat are set up?

Comment: ... yes...? It has rep = main. It's called "meta" = meta.

Comment: @Catija Are those the definitions used for the hats?

Comment: Dunno. But I'm guessing Yaakov did it on purpose. I'll let him explain.

Comment: Apparently, it is both, according to your screenshot. Which makes sense.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/115866

Answer (score 3):

MSE is both a Meta and Main site for the purposes of WinterBash. Really, it is a main site. But there are often hats awarded for things related specifically to meta-activities (like using meta-only tags). In recognition of this special status, you can earn both the [main](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/social-distancing-main) and [meta](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/social-distancing-meta) versions of this hat on MSE.

> Meta Stack Exchange
> Is it Main? Is it Meta?
> For Winter Bash: Both!