# Cumulative Winter Bash hat data

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, community-data, winter-bash-2022

Is there anywhere that data could be found regarding Winter Bash hats, such as how many of each hat have been earned, when such hats were first earned, and the amount of each hat earned per site? I remember that Stack Exchange used to release data following the Winter Bash in prior years, but could there be (or is there) a tracker that users could use to view such data during the Winter Bash itself?

Comment: There’s never been a tracker during Winter Bash itself. The devs usually release a page `/stats` with the information you mentioned after the event ends.

Comment: ...there's some information at /unicorn as well...

Comment: That’s a [long-running hidden Easter egg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns+winter-bash).

Comment: Looking forward to it at winterba.sh !

Comment: @Rob 2022 hats are up now btw!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the staff do have access to a stats page that lists a variety of cool data points, this isn't visible to the public. While there may not be significant risk that I can think of to keep it private, it does link to a variety of users who might otherwise go unnoticed and gives precise time stamps of when the hat was earned (some caching involved), which would make it quite a bit easier for some of y'all to suss out the triggers of secret hats... which kinda makes the game less fun. ;)

If you're curious, it shows us the following info:

- The username and timestamp for the first time each hat was earned (up to five simultaneous users). It's one list for all hats but shows secret hats in bold to make it a bit easier to find them.
- A list ordered by number of times each type of hat has been awarded network-wide including both the total number of hats and the total distinct users to earn that hat, which only counts a user once, even if they've earned the hat a dozen times.

The second list also includes the hats that have not yet been awarded.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, one of the reasons I was looking for such data in the first place was, indeed, to figure out more triggers. :P

Comment: Will this data be released post-winterbash once the event ends though, as has been the case previously?

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHA - I just noticed that this question has a data tag. Yes, we have a wrap-up blog with placeholders for much of this information.

Comment: @Catija so are the hats randomly delayed in reporting? Or reported on a schedule?

Comment: @JamesRisner That's really a separate question but it gives out the hats every 10 minutes or so. I think some have longer caches but most are about that.

Comment: @JamesRisner: Related – [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245122/335251) – particularly the last section ("Caching / scheduling").